# How can I see a city's border growth forecast?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ V on city screen there was ability to see which tiles the city will acquire next and how soon. How can i see that in Civ VI?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of the "Civilization VI Fall 2016 Update", this is now viewable by default.

[image]

---

At launch, in the base game, there was no way to see when or where the next border expansion will take place.

Comment: To be complete, this still does not notify you in case of priority-ties, like it used to in Civ V. If a city will expand to one of the 2+ tiles (chosen at random) because they have same priority, the UI will only show you one of them.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a mod [Next City Plot](http://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/next-city-plot-by-ace.25437/), which shows when and where the city will expand upon the next growth of cultural borders.